# Android make ImageView use dark theme resource

Tags: android

I have a section of my application that should be in dark theme during "private" mode while the remainder of the app remains in light theme. For most of the `View`s, I set the tint dynamically depending on the "private mode". We have 1 `ImageView` where I can't set the tint (since part of it has a different color). Is there a way to make the `ImageView` use it's dark theme resource dynamically?

Comment: please can show to us what you have tried?

Comment: My current plan is to separate the dark and light theme into 2 separate image resources, and set them dynamically, but this increases the size of the application and is harder to maintain. I've researched various ways of setting dark theme, but they are done on the Activity layer which makes it hard to only set a single view into dark theme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the theme attribute of the view you want to use dark mode to like

```
 theme="<dark theme>"
```

That should override your default theme

If you want to change it at run time just use a variable. I.E

```
if (isDarkMode) imageView.tint = Color.BLACK
```